# Creating a handles for each new item in a dropdownitems

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, foreach

I have a ToolStripMenuItem that when I put the mouse hover, it show a list of txt files. I need that when I click one of those items it opens that file with notepad (or the default text editor.)

```
    Private Sub CFGMenu_DropDownOpening() Handles CFGMenu.MouseHover
    CFGMenu.DropDownItems.Clear()
    Dim cfgfolderpath As String
    cfgfolderpath = SrcdsExePathTextBox.Text & "\" & GameMod & "\cfg"
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(cfgfolderpath) Then
        'Create new submenu for each cfg file
        For Each CfgFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles _
                (cfgfolderpath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.cfg")
            CFGMenu.DropDownItems.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CfgFile))
        Next
    Else
        Status.Text = "The 'cfg' folder is empty or doesn't exist!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's how it looks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4iF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the *Handles* keyword when you dynamically add items.  You **must** use the AddHandler statement.  Just use a common event handler for all the Click events, like this:

```
    Dim text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CfgFile)
    Dim item As ToolStripItem = CfgMenu.DropDownItems.Add(text)
    item.Tag = CfgFile   '' We'll need this later for Notepad
    AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf CfgMenuItems_Click
```

And the Click event handler, it needs to recover the item that was clicked from the *sender*:

```
Private Sub CfgMenuItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim item = CType(sender, ToolStripItem)
    Dim path = CStr(item.Tag)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", path)
End Sub
```

Comment: Id works! I changed the last line with Process.Start(path) and now it opens the file with Notepad++
Ty!